# com.facebook.sdk error 2 occurs when login to Facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I am trying to use Facebook plugin for phone gap but getting error message

> "the operation couldn't be completed com.facebook.error 2"

I guess my bundle identifier does not match for Facebook but I am not sure 
what I missed for bundle identifier match... check if my code missing 
something for bundle identifier matching?

deviceready function :

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
     try {
       alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
       FB.init({ appId: "120048634820284", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
       document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
     } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
     }
}, false);
```

info.plist file

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.mycompany.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBUndleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb120048634820284</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error and finally solved it. The app was configured on Sandbox mode and the facebook user I was using wasn't added to testers group.

An administrator can solve it here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Answer (score 4):

Sign out of facebook app from the settings and then try.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

check facebook in settings, you will see off in front your application name, turn it on and it will sove your problem.

But still this is not perfect solution, i am too looking for solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

be sure to have correct bundle identifier in your app settings on developers.facebook.com

Answer (score -1):

It seems fine on a real device. sdk error 2 only occurs on ios simulator. This still bugging me out

but as long as a device throws no errors, fine then..